# Error while executing perl application in locate.pl

Tags: windows, perl

This is the error:

```
No 'new' for class 'Spec::Benchmark::bzip2401' in 'C:/Users/Tester/Documents/SpecINT2k6_WoT/benchspec/CPU2006/401.bzip2/Spec/object.pm'
```

point of error in locate.pl file:

```
my $class="Spec::Benchmark::${name}${num}";
                if (!$class->can('new')) {
                    Log(0, "\nNo 'new' for class '$class' in '$pm'\n");
                    next;
                }
```

here is the link to the whole locate.pl file http://ks.tier2.hep.manchester.ac.uk/Repositories/other-software/SPEC_CPU2006v1.1/bin/locate.pl

This is the object.pm file http://codepad.org/O196ykIq

I am getting this error while running Specint2006 suite, but this error is not related to the suite. Can anyone tell me what does `!$class->can('new')` do and why is it returning true here?

Thanks.

Comment: `can` checks if the class/object has a method called `new`, it's documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html

Comment: @Qtax So how do I resolve this? The locate.pl file came with the package and I have neither edited it and nor do I intend to. Is there some other way to include the `new` method for the `$class`

Answer (score 1):

Can checks if the Class has the method. The return value is always the coderef. If the class dont know the method, the return value is *undef*. 
The Class dont know the new method, so its false. But you call it with **not**

```
!$class->can('new')
```

Quote from [HERE](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html)

*Again, the same rule about having a valid invocand applies -- use an eval block or blessed if you need to be extra paranoid.*

Comment: How do I make the `$class` 'know' the `new` method?

Comment: You can write the method inside your package. Or do you want to trick out the 'can' test?

Comment: Tricking the `can` test is more viable option here, because the suite performs checksum so this will mean more errors :) Thanks again for the timely help

Comment: You can define a subroutine outside its package by explicitly qualifying the name of the subroutine: `sub Some_package::foo { ... }   # &foo defined in Some_package` seen [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)

Comment: Can't I skip the can test in entirety(can't I avoid writing any extra code)?

Comment: Isn't it the point the code is for? Checking if the Module know the Method or not. Lol i really have no idea why you should skip that test :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32343/discussion-between-capricorn-and-paulchenkiller)